# Shape to shape morph

Tags: java, shapes

Straight to the main question - are there any libraries which implement morphing one `java.awt.Shape` object into another one? Under morphing here I generally mean possibility to create some kind intermediate shape for given two and some progress value. Something like (just my vision):

```
Shape shape1 = ...;
Shape shape2 = ...;
float progress = 0.35f;
Shape intermediate = SomeShapeUtils.intermediate( shape1, shape2, progress );
```

Shapes could be anything and might have different amount of points in them like:

```
Shape shape1 = new Ellipse2D.Double( 0, 0, 100, 100 );
Shape shape2 = new Line2D.Double( 0, 0, 100, 0 );
```

Generally it seems to be possible to implement this, but it will require a lot to be taken into consideration unless case is simplified to some simple shapes/conditions/restrictions which is much less interesting and harder to use on practice as I might not be able to control shape.

So before I started inventing a wheel I wanted to know if there are any existing solutions.
Thanks for any hints in advance!

Comment: *Generally it seems to be possible to implement this* how? How would you morph an ellipse to a line? Would you cut the ellipse and unravel it? Would you squish and stretch the ellipse (how would this work for a shape consisting of two parallel lines)? Which one of those would generally be correcter than the other? You can generally only morph shapes that share the same [topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topology) (e.g. an ellipse to a rectangle).

Comment: I agree that there is no single and only correct solution and it might look like there is no possible solution at all unless shapes share the same topology. Though if you look at each shape as a sequence of points and commands of how those points are connected (like: line[from,to], quad[from,control,to], etc.) it becomes kind of a different issue - you only need to morph sequence taken from the first shape into sequence from the second shape. And of course there could be various options to achieve different visual output. I am wondering if there is at least some implementation of that idea :)